# Does codenameone has something equivalent to Android's bound services?

Tags: android, codenameone

I am looking to replace the Android bound services (Binder/IBinder) used in my existing code to make it work with codenameone then create an iOS app. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IBinder/Binder in the Android native code that you integrate with your application. But it has no equivalent in other OSs so we can't create a portable abstraction for it.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I will look into Android native code integration in codenameone. Is my understanding correct that I should minimize the use of Android native code in order to take the most advantage of codenameone (less native iOS code)?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. That code will only run when working on Android.